# Client-Server communication in REST, Spring (RestTemplate): getting 404 error

Tags: http, rest, spring-mvc, client-server, resttemplate

I am trying to setup a Client-Server communication in REST, Spring.

In the client side I have the code:

```
Map<String, Double> variable = new HashMap<String, Double>(1);
variable.put(newTicket.getMovieName(),newTicket.getTicketPrice());
try{    
     Boolean rresult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm", Boolean.class, variable);
```

In the server side I have the code (to receive the above 'variable', and get the below boolean as a return object):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/movieTheater/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public boolean getCustomerInput(Map<String, Double> input) {
    return transactionService.addTransaction(input);
}
```

I am not sure if the above syntax is correct. When I am running the two servers, I am getting the following error at the client side(8080):

```
GET request for "http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler
```

Please let me know what I am missing here, and what changes I need to make in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the wrong url to call the Web Service

```
http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm
```

This ends with .htm whereas your RequestMapping does not contains this request pattern

Update:

Make sure there no console errors and also, if your server application is running on 8081.

Comment: Inside my web.xml I have:                                     <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVCMerchant</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: But did you update the request mapping on the controller from movieTheater to movieTheater.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But since I have *.htm in web.xml, I assumed I don't need to have .htm in my request mapping. But still I addded it as you said and it is still not working.

Comment: I just realized I was having wrong <context:component-scan base-package in SpringMVCMerchant-servlet.xml. I fixed it and restarted Tomcat and now getting a different error. I have posted it as a new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090379/using-tomcat-but-getting-classnotfoundexception-org-jboss-logging-basiclogger)