# Using Tomcat, but getting ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, rest, jboss, tomcat7

I am using Tomcat 7 in Eclipse for running a REST Spring web application with JPA Hibernate. I am getting a strange JBoss error while trying to start Tomcat with my app deployed in it. I don't understand why I am getting a JBoss error when I am using Tomcat. Here's the server log:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 38 more
Aug 7, 2013 2:24:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 38 more
Aug 7, 2013 2:24:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 7, 2013 2:24:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Please help me resolve this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was this after a Java upgrade to version 6u51?

Comment: No, I am using the default workbench Java. I have JRE7. But FYI, I ran a similar application in my machine sometime ago in Eclipse Tomcat, and it ran fine. Thanks!

Comment: You can try the advice offered in this question's answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615566/java-noclassdeffound-error

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at the link and trying to locate the jars. But what I don't understand is, why I need JBoss jars when I am running Tomcat server!! Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess, you are missing a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The error is solved! Though, I still don't understand why I need JBoss Jar for Tomcat!

Comment: Its not about the server. Its about hibernate which is using JBoss Logger

Comment: @kajarigd Can you also accept my last answer as in that was another bug in your code?