# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after installing to another tomcat server 8.5.35

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8

Before saying this is a duplicate, i've seen most of the related problems to this but none worked for me :( I have a web app which is installed perfectly on our server, when i installed it on another backup web server (Centos, apache 8.5.35, jdk 1.8) This exception error happens and it does not upload the web app :( this server contains 3 web apps, all spring projects, 2 are working but one. below is the error:

```html
2018-12-13 10:40:14,411 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2356)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:830)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1297)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1156)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:183)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1328)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1156)
        ... 40 more
13-Dec-2018 10:40:14.413 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

I'm sure there are no dependencies missing when i imported this as it was from a tar.gz and i tried a lot, reinstalling java jdk and tomcat, reimporting the webapps. I hope someone can help.

Comment: it does look like, you are missing jboss logger; atleast not available in the classpath set in there; also looks very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090379/using-tomcat-but-getting-classnotfoundexception-org-jboss-logging-basiclogger?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi @TechJunkie how come its not missing when its from another server? im really confused. I just imported the webapps by tar.gz and i somehow gets this error :( i've read this article also before i posted this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!! It turns out i was not missing any dependency, i read on an article that using hibernate 4.0.2 is better than 5.0.2 for some reason. And i found out from my classes lib that there were 2 hibernate validators ' hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar' and 'hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar' so i removed the 5.0.1 version. I also checked the logs from catalina and the working servers are running 4.0.1 while the server that shows this error are running 5.0.1 thats why i removed it from the classpath.

EDIT: See comment below for explanation as to why it worked

Comment: Glad that you found the cause; btw, you were indeed missing a dependency for hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar; issue went off because you have taken that jar out.

Comment: Ohhhhhh thats why, thanks! ill edit my answer with this :D